# Help Understanding the Logic Behind these Integration Limits

Tags: probability, integration, limits

I was reading this reference here (https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/order_stats.pdf) on page 9.

Over here, an equation is given regarding the Joint Probability Distribution of Order Statistics:

$f_{X_{(2)}}\dots f_{X_{(n)}} (x_2,\dots,x_n) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_2}f_{X_{(1)}} f_{X_{(2)}}\dots f_{X_{(n)}}\dots (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \,\mathrm{d}x_1$

**I am having difficulty understanding why the integration limits in the above equation are from negative infinity to x2.**

In my opinion, the integration limits should have been from "negative infinity" to "x1" - this is because the integration variable itself is "x1".

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since we are talking about order statistics, note that $X_{1} < X_{2}$. So all possible values that $X_{1}$ can assume are bounded by the realization of $X_{2}$. Moreover, if you are integrating wrt a variable $x$, then having the same variable as the limit of integration is not a valid expression.

Comment: @ sudeep5221: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, I would be really interested in hearing about this. Maybe you can post an answer? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have posted an answer. Hope that helps to clarify things a bit!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier to think of this with just two variables. Consider two i.i.d. random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and let $ X_{(1)} = \min \{X_1, X_2\}$ and $ X_{(2)} = \max \{X_1, X_2\}$ denote the order statistics. Consider the joint distribution of $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ denoted by $f(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)})$. Note that the support of this joint distribution will only be in the region $x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)}$ because by definition $x_{(1)}$ can never be greater than $x_{(2)}$. So when we are interested in finding the marginal of $x_{(2)}$ and integrate out $x_{(1)}$, the integral looks as follows:
\begin{align*}
f_{X_{(2)}}(x_{(2)}) & = \int_{\{x_{(1)}: x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)}\}} f(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}) \ \mathrm{d} x_{(1)} \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{x_{(2)}} f(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}) \ \mathrm{d} x_{(1)},
\end{align*}
which is exactly the same as what you have in the question.

In other words, since we are consider the joint distribution of the order statistics, distribution is not supported over the entire reals because order statistics enforce an order among the possible values the variables can take. This ends up affecting the limits of the integration.